# GridView asp.net форматированный текст

Tags: база-данных, visual-studio, asp.net

Использую GridView, текст теряет всё форматирование как при просмотре, так и при редактировании.
Сделал столбцы TemplateField. В редакторе шаблона для EditItemTemplate и ItemTemplate выбрал TextBox. Поставил ему MultiLine и wrap.

Но всё равно выглядит некрасиво.
Возможно не стоит использовать TextBox, но для Label нет свойств MultiLine и wrap.
Что посоветуете чтобы сохранять форматирование текста?

Comment: разметку покажите для `TemplateField`. и что значит _теряет всё форматирование_?

Comment: Пропадают пробелы. Переносы строк.

Comment: это потому что вы сохраняете как текст, а не html.